# How do i know which pods are covered by a network policy in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have a use case where I want to check which pods are covered by a network policy, right now my focus is only k8s generated network policies.

What's the easiest way to do this? I know we can go through each network policy and from there filter out pods but a network policy can have multiple ways in which one uses the pod filtering. I am not sure if there is a way to tackle every possible pod filter on the network policy and then get the list of the pods from it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the **podSelector** field you can check all the pods that are covered by a Network Policy. Using the label mentioned in podSelector you can retrieve the list of pods which are using the NetworkPolicy.

Each NetworkPolicy includes a **podSelector** which selects the grouping of pods to which the policy applies. Let us consider an example policy which contains a **podSelector** with the label “role=db”. The example policy selects pods with the label "role=db". An empty podSelector selects all pods in the namespace.

When you run NetworkPolicy, you can check the label used for a podSelector by describing the networkpolicy.

```
$ kubectl describe networkpolicy <networkpolicy-name>
```

Pod selector will show you which labels this network policy applied too. Then you can present all the pods with this label by:

```
$ kubectl get pods -l <podSelector>
```

Refer [NetworkPolicy resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#networkpolicy-resource) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Change **netpolName** in the below command and run:

```sh
kubectl get pod -l \
  $( \
        kubectl get netpol netpolName \
        -o jsonpath="{.spec.podSelector.matchLabels}"| \
        jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value)")[]' \
  )
```