# How can we find all network policies associate to a pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Is there a way to find out all ingress and egress policies that a pod could be affected from?

I haven't written any netpol for a pod, but my pod lives in a huge cluster with many other netpolicies. Based on the timeout errors that I see, I suspect that there are some netpolicies that are getting applied to my pod.

How do I see the list of network policies that affect my little pod?

Thank you

p.s: My question is the inverse of [How do i know which pods are covered by a network policy in k8s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71725765/how-do-i-know-which-pods-are-covered-by-a-network-policy-in-k8s) I would like to know list of netpolicies for a pod.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
kubectl describe networkpolicy <network-policy-name>
```

Check the label used for the `Pod Selector`. Then list the pods by their `pod selector` name

```
kubectl get pods -l <pod selector name>
```

It should list the pods that are part of the network policy that you described

Comment: There are so many network policies in the cluster tedious to do `describe` for every netpol manually